# Dimension of solution space of the the matrix equation AX=0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-rank

> **Q.2 :** Let $T \in \textsf{M}_{m \times n} (\mathbb R)$. Let $\textsf V$ be a subspace of $\textsf{M}_{n \times p} (\mathbb R)$ defined by
> $$\textsf V = \{ X \in \textsf{M}_{m \times n} (\mathbb R) : \, TX = 0 \}.$$
> Then the dimension of $\textsf V$ is :
>
> $$\begin{matrix}
> (\textrm A) \, pn - \operatorname{rank} T & (\textrm B) \, mn - p\operatorname{rank} T \\
> (\textrm C) \, p(m - \operatorname{rank} T) & (\textrm D) \, p(n - \operatorname{rank} T)
> \end{matrix}$$

My attempt :

Consider $TX = 0$. Then there are $mp$ homogeneous equations with $np$ unknowns. The dimension of $\textsf V$ will be number of independent entries of the matrix $X$ satisfying $TX=0$. I tried to use rank-nullity theorem of linear transformation but I am not getting any conclusion.

How to proceed from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might consider the following linear application
$$ \varphi_T : {\cal M}_{np} \ni M \mapsto (TM_1,\ldots, TM_p) \in \left(\mathbb{R}^m\right)^p.$$
Apply the null-rank theorem to $\varphi_T$ and compare $(Im(T))^p$ and $Im(\varphi_T)$.

Comment: Got it!!! The answer will be p(n- rank(T)).Am I right?

Comment: Check it on some simple examples. First, keep in mind that for $p=1$ you should have $n-rk(T)$, then for $p=2$ try some simple examples.
In the definition of $\varphi_T$ in my first comment, $M_1,\ldots,M_p$ are the $p$ columns of $M$.